# sum integers from n to its square(inclusive)

Tags: sequences-and-series

A question asks me to find the sum of integers from n to its square (inclusive)

I have come up with:
$$
Sn = n+(n+1)+(n+2)....+(n^2-1)+n^2
$$
$$
Sn = n^2+(n^2-1)+(n^2-2)...+(n+1)+n
$$
$$
2Sn = (n^2+n)*(n^2+n+1)$$ [there are $n^2+n+1$ terms from n to $n^2$]

However my textbook's answer for the sum to be $1/2n(n^3+1)$?
I am not really sure where I went wrong, would appreciate some help to guide me!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of terms is $n^{2}-n+1$, not $n^{2}+n+1$.

Also $\frac 1 2 (n^{2}+n)(n^{2}-n+1)=\frac  1 2 n(n^{3}+1)$.

Comment: May I ask you how did you get n^2-n+1, I tried listing out some sequences and counting the number of terms e.g. 2+3+4 (3 terms), 3+4+5...9 (7 terms),4+5+6...16 (13 terms) and iI found a general sequence for the number of terms to be n^2+n+1

Comment: How many number are there between $k$ and $n$ (for $1 \leq k <n$)? There are $n$ numbers form $1$ to $n$ and $k-1$ from $1$ to $k-1$. Take the difference between these to get the answer.